# Save attribute of model in database in PHP in OctoberCMS

Tags: php, database, attributes, save

Hi I have problem when i tried to save attribute of model to database. I write in OctoberCMS and i have this function:

```
public function findActualNewsletter()
    {
        $actualNewsletter = Newsletter::where('status_id', '=', NewsletterStatus::getSentNowStatus())->first();
        if (!$actualNewsletter) {
            $actualNewsletter = Newsletter::where('send_at', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))->where('status_id', NewsletterStatus::getUnsentStatus())->first();

            $actualNewsletter->status_id = NewsletterStatus::getSentNowStatus();
            dd($actualNewsletter);
        }
        return $actualNewsletter;
    }
```

> getSentNowStatus()=2;
>
> getUnsentStatus()=1;

dd($actualNewsletter) in my if statement show that status_id = 2 But in database i still have 1. I used this function in afterSave() so i dont need:

```
  $actualNewsletter->status_id = NewsletterStatus::getSentNowStatus();
  $actualNewsletter->save();
```

becosue i have error then i use save in save.
Of course i filled table $fillable =['status_id']. And now i dont know why its not save in database when it go to my if. Maybe someone see my mistake?

Comment: I've never used OctoberCMS, but it looks like you should `->save()` your model so it persists. https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#basic-updates

Comment: but i used this in function afterSave() {there is my function}so i tried to use with ->save() problem must be in other place

Comment: i tired to use save() i write about this in my post but it still not save my attribute to database

Comment: If you are using this in an "afterSave" callback, then the save action has already occurred. Is there a "beforeSave" callback you can use instead?

Comment: yes i tried to use this beforeSave too it th same effect

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to modify the model based on some custom logic and then save it, the best place to put it is in the `beforeSave()` method of the model. To access the current model being saved, just use `$this`. Below is an example of the `beforeSave()` method being used to modify the attributes of a model before it gets saved to the database:

```
public function beforeSave() {
    $user = BackendAuth::getUser();
    $this->backend_user_id = $user->id;

    // Handle archiving
    if ($this->is_archived && !$this->archived_at) {
        $this->archived_at = Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
    }

    // Handle publishing
    if ($this->is_published && !$this->published_at) {
        $this->published_at = Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
    }

    // Handle unarchiving
    if ($this->archived_at && !$this->is_archived) {
        $this->archived_at = null;
    }

    // Handle unpublishing, only allowed when no responses have been recorded against the form
    if ($this->published_at && !$this->is_published) {
        if (is_null($this->responses) || $this->responses->isEmpty()) {
            $this->published_at = null;
        }
    }
}
```

You don't have to run `$this->save()` or anything like that. Simply modifying the model's attributes in the `beforeSave()` method will accomplish what you desire.

Comment: but i used this in beforeSave and then its no effect. Secondly I finnaly want to use this function not in beforeSave but in taskSchedule with use cron where it should automatically work on my database. I mean automaticaly search record with status and if there is no record with this status then find with criteria in my if statement and then overwrite status_id of this record. And now i use this ->save() in cron but this still not save my data